# Ionic: ERESOLVE could not resolve: Found: rxjs@7.x.x

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs7

Does anyone encounter this issue when trying to build ionic project with capacitor?

I have an Ionic project which has different packages for each functionality. I am trying to export my project into the android studio using `ionic capacitor build android`. I have also tried creating a new project with blank pages and it worked fine. My suspicions here is the native packages but i dont know how to resolve this since i am new to angular and ionic.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ionic-native/core@5.36.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/common@15.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.0.2" from @angular/forms@15.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.3.9
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         @ionic/angular@"^6.3.9" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.0.2" from @angular/platform-browser@15.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"15.0.2" from @angular/forms@15.0.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.3.9
npm ERR!         node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/core@15.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!     peer @angular/core@"15.0.2" from @angular/common@15.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!       peer @angular/common@"15.0.2" from @angular/forms@15.0.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@">=12.0.0" from @ionic/angular@6.3.9
npm ERR!         node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       4 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/core@"15.0.2" from @angular/compiler@15.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!       peer @angular/compiler@"15.0.2" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.0.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!         peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.0.2
npm ERR!         node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!         2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
npm ERR!       2 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, the root project)
npm ERR!     7 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/forms, @angular/router, @ionic/angular, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/core@5.36.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/core
npm ERR!   peer @ionic-native/core@"^5.1.0" from @ionic-native/network@5.36.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/network
npm ERR!     @ionic-native/network@"^5.36.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: rxjs@6.6.7
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/core@5.36.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/core
npm ERR!     peer @ionic-native/core@"^5.1.0" from @ionic-native/network@5.36.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic-native/network
npm ERR!       @ionic-native/network@"^5.36.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a dependency conflict, probably because the `@ionic-native` wrappers are not updated anymore and the Ionic is using the latest Angular 15.

Try replacing all of your `@ionic-native` packages for their `@awesome-cordova-plugins` counterparts.

EX 1: `npm un @ionic-native/core && npm i @awesome-cordova-plugins/core`

EX 2: `npm un @ionic-native/social-sharing && npm i @awesome-cordova-plugins/social-sharing`

And so on...

if you encounter the same error while doing that, add the --force flag after each npm i command.