# Can I create an Ionic app that runs offline on a Windows machine with an SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I am trying to create a prototype of an Ionic+Angular application that can run offline on a Windows machine (by using Capacitor and Electron) and can store data in an SQLite database.

However, after I start the app (`npx cap open electron`) the database is not created with the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')"
```

**How can I fix this error?**

This is the code where the database is initialized:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Song } from './song';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SQLitePorter } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/sqlite-porter/ngx';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/sqlite/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class DbService {
  private storage: SQLiteObject;
  songsList: any = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private isDbReady: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private sqlite: SQLite,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private sqlPorter: SQLitePorter
  ) {
    this.initDb();
  }

  initDb() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.sqlite
        .create({
          name: 'positronx_db.db',
          location: 'default',
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          this.storage = db;
          this.getFakeData();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

I successfully created an empty ionic app using Capacitor and Electron to wrap it to run as a desktop application on Windows by following [this tutorial](https://trailheadtechnology.com/creating-ios-android-and-desktop-apps-from-your-angular-web-app-using-ionic-capacitor-and-electron/).

To add the SQLite database I followed [this tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/ionic-sqlite-database-crud-app-example-tutorial/). Initially I got some dependency conflict error, but following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711601/ionic-eresolve-could-not-resolve-found-rxjs7-x-x) I replaced the `@ionic-native` packages with `@awesome-cordova-plugins` which resolved the dependency conflict error, leaving me with the error described above.

I found [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-6-capacitor-and-local-database-sqlite/220152/4) which describes my problem pretty accurately and suggests to use Web SQL, since apparently the sqlite plugin cannot be used in a browser. Web SQL is deprecated though, and since I want to have a Windows desktop app I don't necessarily need it to work in a browser. **Is there any way to work around this restriction?**

I tried using a capacitor command to serve the app with electron as the platform (`ionic capacitor run electron`) to run it as a Windows app directly instead of a web app, but then I get
`[ERROR] No devices or emulators found`.
I am not sure how to add a Windows device or emulator, or if this is even the correct approach to fix this issue.

I considered using Ionic Storage instead of SQLite as suggested [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sqlite-and-capacitor-3/211951), but there is a lot of complex relational data and it does need to be completely functional offline, which seems to mean that I need SQLite.

Comment: positronx tutorials are horrible, i've tried to use in the past. The person literally reused old post he created and changes some stuff so it can "look" new and when running code there's all sorts of issues. As far as SQLite plugin, it outdated. You need to look for a capacitor plugin or maybe you should look into: https://rxdb.info/. It works offline too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding [this repository](https://github.com/jepiqueau/ionic7-angular-sqlite-starter/tree/main) which implements a complete starter solution for an Ionic 7 Angular 16 app while using the `@capacitor-community/sqlite` plugin with Capacitor 5 as their offline database.

Initially I had some problems running it with Electron (`npm run electron:start`) and got the error

> The module .\electron\node_modules\better-sqlite3-multiple-ciphers\build\Release\better_sqlite3.node'     was compiled against a different Node.js version using
> NODE_MODULE_VERSION 108. This version of Node.js requires
> NODE_MODULE_VERSION 116. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
> the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)

I was able to fix the error by following the second answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384591/node-was-compiled-against-a-different-node-js-version-using-node-module-versio), executing the commands from the ./electron directory and specifying the electron version for the rebuild command (`node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild -f -w <your-electron-version>`).